# Coloring Cells in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I want to look at a named range of cells in Excel 2013, and if the text in those cells is white, then I want to set the color of the text in the cell to the right of that cell to white as well.  Can anyone please help this pitiful vba programming newb out?  Much appreciated.  Have a great day!

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Range("DateOut").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            Cell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: This:

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("DateOut").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        Cell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End If
Next

End Sub

Comment: update your question with this code - it's unreadable in comments

Comment: Sorry, how do you make it show code in comments @simoco

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Range("DateOut").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            Cell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    Next    
    End Sub
```

which part are you having trouble with?
If you are having trouble with where to add the code

- Right click on the sheet name and select View code and paste it

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     For Each Cell In Range("DateOut")
     If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then Cell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
     Next
End Sub
```